# nodegit - how to get lines added/removed in a commit filewise?

Tags: node.js, git, git-commit, nodegit

I am new to nodegit. I want to see most recent 10 commits for a repo, files changed and changes introduced in respective commits.

I have got list of 10 most recent commits, but I am stuck on getting commit details.

Here is the code that I am using

```
var nodegit = require('nodegit');
var repoPath = "some_repo_path";

//open branch
nodegit.Repository.open(repoPath).then(function(repo){
//get branch
return repo.getCurrentBranch().then(function(ref) {
    console.log("On " + ref.shorthand() + " (" + ref.target() + ")");
    //get commit
    return repo.getBranchCommit(ref.shorthand());
}).then(function(commit) {
    //get commit history
    var history = commit.history();
    p = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        history.on("end", resolve);
        history.on("error", reject);
    });
    history.start();
    return p;
}).then(function(commits){
    //iterate through last 10 commits
    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        var sha = commits[i].sha().substr(0,7),
            msg = commits[i].message().split('\n')[0];
        console.log(sha + " " + msg + " " + commits[i].author() + " " + commits[i].time());
        //get details for this commit
        //number of lines added/removed
        //list of files changed/deleted
        //for each changed file number of lines added/removed
        //for each changes file actual lines added/removed
    }
});
```

});